# Linear Algebra Orthogonality Proof with scalar

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $u, v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that 
      $u⋅v \leq \| u \| ~ \|v \|$

Hint: expand $\| u−cv \|$ for $c \in \mathbb{R}$

I'm confused how to prove this theorem. From the hint, I got $(u-cv)(u-cv)$. Can someone please help understand this concept. Thank you.

Comment: Please $\TeX$ify yourself next time

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Second_proof)

Comment: Please remember that you can choose an aswer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, take a look [here](http://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~matsefi/Octogon/volumes/volume1/article1_19.pdf) for different proofs.

Comment: Actually, C-S shows that $|u \cdot v| $ is less than the RHS, but any proof of that stronger result will also suffice for this weaker one.

Comment: @JohnHughes yes indeed I noticed that and the proof is the same, thanks